# python filtered input to csv.reader

Tags: python, csv

My program reads a csv file but recently the input file was changed to be base64 encoded. So currently the read code is:

```
with open(uploadFile, 'rb') as csvfile:
    spreadSheet = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
```

I know the csv is a file descriptor and this can't be done, but I want to do something like:

```
import base64
with open(uploadFile, 'rb') as csvfile:
   spreadSheet = csv.reader(bas64.decode(csvfile), delimiter=',')
```

That is the file input would be base64 decoded as though in a pipe and then parsed as a csv file.

I can read the file decode it write back into another file and then read that file with the csv reader but that all seems as though there should be a way to do it as a pipe sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
import base64
import csv

with open(uploadFile, 'rb') as csvfile:
    decoded = base64.standard_b64decode(csvfile.read()).decode('utf-8')
    spreadSheet = csv.reader(decoded.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
```

Comment: decoded is a string (type Unicode) I thought the first parameter of csv.reader had to be a filename?   What I was looking for was a way of taking an input file descriptor running its output through a filter (base64) and then from its output creating another file descriptor. The advantage being you can then usethat descriptor to say open a Microsoft spreadsheet using say xlrd

Comment: Maybe something like popen?